# Profiling outliers using Async Profiler

Tags: java, linux, profiling, chronicle, async-profiler

I'm benchmarking my application using chronicle JLBH. Above 99th percentile, it shows there are runs that are taking more than 20micros (up to 99th it's less than 2 micros). I would like to profile the outliers to see what's happening during those 20 micros. I normally use Async Profiler cpu and wall modes to see hot methods and threads states, but it doens't seem to be fit to view runs by time. Is there a way to view profile outliers?

Answer (score 1):

There is a JitterSampler class which is good for finding causes of delays. It runs a background thread that takes samples when a threshold is exceeded.
However to start with I would run your benchmark on /dev/shm to see how much is IO.